# Totem not playing VCD

Tags: 14.04, totem, w64codecs

I am trying to play a VCD, but Totem gives me an error :

```
Videos requires to install plugins to support the following multimedia feature: VCD protocol source
```

So i did

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I still get the same error when i try to play the VCD again after installation, so i try :

```
sudo apt-get install w64codecs libdvdcss2
```

But that gives me the error :

```
Package libdvdcss2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package w64codecs
E: Package 'libdvdcss2' has no installation candidate
```

Any way to make Totem play the VCD?

Answer (score 1):

`libdvdcss2` isn't a "standard" package and has to be installed the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh # This downloads and installs libdvdcss2
```

This should make Totem play your VCD. You may also want to make sure you have gstreamer's plugins to play some patent-encumbered formats:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently there is no solution for this problem. But you can try other media players like VLC. It plays almost everything.

Comment: I have a question on VLC as well http://askubuntu.com/questions/472963/vlc-unable-to-open-mrl :)