# VLC unable to open MRL

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I am trying to play a VCD using :

```
/usr/bin/vlc vcd://
```

But i get the error below :

```
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x14ec1c8] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1486118] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x1486118] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x7f815c0009b8] main input error: open of `vcd://' failed
[0x7f815c0009b8] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[0x7f815c0009b8] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'vcd://'. Check the log for details.
```

Any way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on my Ubuntu 22.04.
I tried to search for solutions everywhere, but none worked.

---

### What did work for me then?

1. I was getting this error for a file that was generated by OBS.
2. I had installed OBS with the snap store, so the default export URL was inside the snap directory.
3. I just copied the media files into public directories, like Videos.

---

And it worked. May be some kind of issue with file accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

I installed `vlc` package instead of `vlc-nox` and that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed

```
sudo apt install browser-plugin-vlc
```

And it fixed everything, now I can play files from network and from mounted drives.

Comment: Not working anymore after Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

On 22.04.1:
Package browser-plugin-vlc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).